# How can I log case class creation in scala?

Tags: scala, logging, case-class

I want to log case class creation, but there doesn't seem to be something like a postCreate() method available.  Is there a way to log case class creation in Scala?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The body of any class (including case classes) in Scala can contain expressions that would be executed upon construction, so you can place any logging / initialization code simply as expressions in the class body (outside of any method):

```
case class MyData(str: String) {
  println(s"got: $str") // executed upon construction
}
```